# What is the performance impact of string casting in C?

Tags: c, performance, casting

In order to use `strncmp` to compare two `unsigned char *` buffers, I have to cast them to `const char *`.

I'm writing a computationally heavy program, and this test appears in one of the most critical parts.
Is it better to write my own comparison function with `unsigned char *` buffers ?

I mean, does the casting to `const char *` from `unsigned char *` affects the computational load ?

Comment: No, it does nothing apart from fooling the compiler.

Comment: (But hey, did you look at the generated assembly?)

Comment: No, I don't know assembly yet :/

Comment: Then you are operating on blind faith

Comment: @Esailija That's not fair. You know how to build microprocessors, and how the quantum mechanics of silicon work?

Comment: @sje397 Hm. Don't exaggerate. If one wants to fine-tune a computationally heavy tight loop, and doesn't want to commit the horrible crime called "premature optimization", he **really really really** needs to know assembly.

Comment: @sje397 What does that have to do with anything? You *completely* missed my point. Are you those people who say "the compiler will optimize it" and never even look at assembly - and if they did, they find out that it wasn't in fact optimized like you expected.

Comment: @H2CO3 It totally depends on what 'heavy' is, which is subjective, and what the requirements are. You might need to build hardware. Or, asking here and not learning assembly could be fine. Some people are busy with other equally valid stuff.

Comment: I've read your messages, and want you to know that I'm stuck with professional timing constraints and limited (I'm still student) knowledge background. I hope one day I'll be able to check myself my assembly code. But for now I run gcc -O3 and can't go very further. You're all right. Don't worry, I'm still reading books :)

Comment: @A.Méric Run `gcc -O3 -S` for one version, then for the other. You're welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. In that case (casting pointers) you're just skirting the type safety features that are supposed to help protect you at compile time. It won't affect the resulting compiled code.

Answer (score 2):

> does the casting to `const char *` from `unsigned char *` affects the computational load

It does not. It casts a pointer value from type `unsigned char *` to `const char *` and this is a cheap operation that does not require any extra object code to be generated.